# How to update xml file within .ini file while simulation running in omnet++?

Tags: omnet++

I am using NesTing library within omnet++. For scheduling of switch gates a gate control list is defined within a xml file which is loaded by the .ini file. For example,

```
**.n5.eth[3].queue.gateController.initialSchedule = xmldoc("schedules.xml", "/schedule/switch[@name='n5']/port[@id='3']/schedule")
**.n6.eth[1].queue.gateController.initialSchedule = xmldoc("schedules.xml", "/schedule/switch[@name='n6']/port[@id='1']/schedule")
**.n6.eth[2].queue.gateController.initialSchedule = xmldoc("schedules.xml", "/schedule/switch[@name='n6']/port[@id='2']/schedule")
```

I would like to change the parameters of that 'schedules.xml' file dynamically and want that the updated file will be re-read by the configuration file so that the updated GCL will be implemented. I can ofcourse, give some more information to clear my question if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe NesTing is not prepared to change the parameters and scheduling on the fly. So you cannot do that.

Comment: Apart from that, I would strongly suggest checking the current master branch (meant to be version 4.4) of the INET framework because there is a ton of new TSN functionality there. It is meant to be the successor of both the Core4INET and the NesTing project. The configuration is also more fine grained, and it's using INI file directly instead of ML files. check the showcases/tsn foder for examples.

Comment: I have been actually searching for the newest INET 4.4 branch after watching the latest omnet conference  2021 videos but on the website, the latest version shows 4.3.7.  I have not yet explored the omnet 6 version much yet. But would it be possible to change parameters and schedule on the fly in the latest 4.4 version?

Comment: I don't think you can change the value of configuration during the simulation, but with OMNeT++ 6 it's relatively easy to tell. If a parameter is annotated with `@mutable` then the model is prepared to handle changes during runtime. If `@mutable` is not present, then it is read only during the initialization phase.

Comment: Taking look at the codebase, you might be lucky. The `GateCheduleConfiguratorBase` indicates that the `configuration` parameter is `@mutable`, so you CAN change that during runtime.